# Base class set to derived class, can't call a method in derived class?

Tags: c#, java, oop, object

This is a general OOP question for languages that do not support inheritance from multiple classes (not sure if that matters here, just thought I'd put that detail in), like Java:

OK, you have your base class:

```
class Base {}

class Derived extends Base
{
   SomeMethod(){}
}

Main()
{
    Base baseInstance = new Base();
    Derived derivedInstance = new Derived();

    baseInstance = derivedInstance;

    baseInstance.someMethod();            <<<<<< this does not work. why?

}
```

Why, when you set the baseInstance to the derivedInstance, is it unable to call the method that is defined in the Derived class?

Since you're setting the baseInstance to be the derivedInstance, should you not have access to this method?

Comment: Because compiler has no idea which derived class instance is assigned to a variable with the `Base` type. Also variable `baseInstance` is of type `Base` which itself does not have method `SomeMethod` defined. If  you want that all classes derived from `Base` had `SomeMethod` but not sure about implementation, make `Base` class abstract and define `SomeMethod` as abstract method, so you'll override later.

Comment: It does not know the type of the baseInstance variable, you're saying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable that is typed as the base class cannot presume methods about subclasses. For example, for all the **compiler** knows, `baseInstance` could hold a reference to a `Base`, or to a `SomeOtherClass extends Base`. Now, you could say that *in this case* the compiler could figure it out, but: that **isn't what the compiler does**. The rules of the compiler are simple: if you have a variable typed as `Base`, you can only use things known on `Base`.

If you want to use specialized methods from specific sub-classes, then you'll need to ask the compiler to perform a cast with type-check, i.e.

```
Derived special = (Derived)baseInstance; // I'm using C# syntax here,
special.someMethod();                    // but should be similar or identical
```

Comment: Java syntax is identical. That comment is odd, imho. +1 anyways.

Comment: yes, in this case it is, but he clearly had c# on the brain :P

Comment: great answer, thank you. i'll give you the check in 8 mins (stack is forcing an 8 minute wait before the check is given)

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
baseInstance = derivedInstance;
```

doesn't set `baseInstance` to type `Derived`. It's still type `Base`.

You can only call `someMethod()` on an object of type `Base` if `someMethod` is a method defined in `Base`. The compiler does *not* know about more derived methods.

Answer (score 1):

In java **instances are created at runtime**, so the actual class **instance gets resolved at run-time** and not during compilation.

Thus, **Compiler always looks at the reference type** to determine which methods or members can be referred by the referencing variable.

In your case, `baseInstance = derivedInstance;` even though the actual class being referred is a subclass of `Base`, compiler will simply assume it to be of the type `Base`. Obviously, `Base` class does not have `someMethod();` hence it does not allow you to call it.

As a work around, you can try this:

```
if(base instanceof Derived) {
 // Downcast it before calling
 ((Derived)baseInstance).someMethod(); 
}
```